# nginx: [emerg] "XXX" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/XXX.conf:7

Tags: nginx

when doing

```
nginx -t
```

error message :

> nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-settings.conf:7

Answer (score 4):

Remove the second copy of the directive from file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-settings.conf` - at line 7.

Comment: Is there another solution? I have set client_max_body_size in a global scope to a high value and want to set it to a lower value in just one server location. Maybe you can solve this by defining an `upstream` and use `proxy_pass` to redirect at the right condition?

Comment: I am not sure about `upstream/proxy_pass` - but if you remove the global setting and put it inside each server block I am sure 100% that it will work. It feels inconvenient - but only if you are changing your config too often (and in this case you should be generating the config automatically using some scripting - not manually) - otherwise the solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

actually i also defined **"client_max_body_size"** in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/XXX.config, so the same variable "client_max_body_size" is duplicated in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-settings.conf - that is the reason it is giving that error.

I resolved by removing the duplicate variable in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-settings.conf :)